# How to find substrings with a certain pattern within a string in Java

Tags: java, regex, data-extraction

I'm using PDFBox to extract the contents of a PDF file. Following which I'll end up with one massive string.

Now, I need to extract all substrings in this string which match the pattern **XX-XXXX**(where the X can be a number or an alphabet) or **XX YYYY** (where X is a alphabet and Y is a number).

I tried ("([A-Z0-9]{2})-([A-Z0-9]{4})") to match the XX - XXXX pattern but it doesn't return me the expected values.

Comment: "How do I do this?": read about regular expressions, try something and if it does not work come back here, show what you tried and ask a specific question.

Comment: ^[A-Z0-9]{2}[-]{1}[A-Z0-9]{4}]*$ Similarly you can make for other also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do a short study about Regular Expressions in Java. Once done have a look at the java.util.regex.Matcher. This helps a lot in finding text on the basis your regex.
Below is a link that will help you a lot.
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-regex/matcher.html